# svg path shifts from it's normal position while rotating

Tags: css, svg, svg-animate

I have a svg clock when i rotate the hand it moves from it's normal position  and also #minute-hand element transform-box property not working in this svg element

note: this svg code generated by illustrator

and another demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ahmed_Fathy/pen/MWbgbEB)

```css
@keyframes rotate-hand{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

/* comment this to see the original hands-shape*/
#seconds-hand, #minutes-hand, #hours-hand{
    animation: rotate-hand 5s linear infinite;
    transform-box: fill-box;
}

#seconds-hand{
/*   animation: rotate-hand 5s linear infinite; */
/*   transform-box: fill-box; */
}

#minutes-hand{
  
}

#hours-hand{
  
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="170.5" height="170.5" viewBox="0 0 170.5 170.5" overflow="scroll">
    <path id="border_1_"
          d="M85.3 0C38.2 0 0 38.2 0 85.3s38.2 85.3 85.3 85.3 85.3-38.2 85.3-85.3S132.3 0 85.3 0zm-1 160c-40.6 0-73.5-32.9-73.5-73.5S43.7 13 84.3 13s75.5 32.9 75.5 73.5-35 73.5-75.5 73.5z"
          fill="#002745"/>

  
    <path id="seconds-hand" transform="rotate(134.355 99.90008916 100.15364826)" fill="#2fc0ea"
          d="M99.1 78.9h1.5v42.5h-1.5z"/>
  
  
    <path id="hours-hand" d="M86.2 88.3h-2.5c-.5 0-1-.4-1-1V48.7c0-.5.4-1 1-1h2.5c.5 0 1 .4 1 1v38.6c0 .6-.5 1-1 1z"
          fill="#002745"/>
  
  
    <path id="minutes-hand"
          d="M69.2 102.7c-.9-.9-.9-2.3-.1-3.1l14.2-14.7c.9-.9 2.3-.9 3.1-.1.9.9.9 2.3.1 3.1l-14.2 14.7c-.8.9-2.2.9-3.1.1z"
          fill="#002745"/>
  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transform-origin:center` is what you need but you have to consider the transform already applied to the `seconds-hand`. I have added a `g` element for it

```css
@keyframes rotate-hand{
  from{transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to{transform: rotate(360deg)}
}

/* comment this to see the original hands-shape*/
#seconds-hand, #minutes-hand, #hours-hand{
    animation: rotate-hand 5s linear infinite;
    transform-origin:center;
}
#minutes-hand {
  animation-duration:2s;
}
#seconds-hand {
  animation-duration:1s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="170.5" height="170.5" viewBox="0 0 170.5 170.5" overflow="scroll">
    <path id="border_1_"
          d="M85.3 0C38.2 0 0 38.2 0 85.3s38.2 85.3 85.3 85.3 85.3-38.2 85.3-85.3S132.3 0 85.3 0zm-1 160c-40.6 0-73.5-32.9-73.5-73.5S43.7 13 84.3 13s75.5 32.9 75.5 73.5-35 73.5-75.5 73.5z"
          fill="#002745"/>

    <g id="seconds-hand">
    <path  transform="rotate(134.355 99.90008916 100.15364826)" fill="#2fc0ea"
          d="M99.1 78.9h1.5v42.5h-1.5z"/>
  
    </g>
    <path id="hours-hand" d="M86.2 88.3h-2.5c-.5 0-1-.4-1-1V48.7c0-.5.4-1 1-1h2.5c.5 0 1 .4 1 1v38.6c0 .6-.5 1-1 1z"
          fill="#002745"/>
  
  
    <path id="minutes-hand"
          d="M69.2 102.7c-.9-.9-.9-2.3-.1-3.1l14.2-14.7c.9-.9 2.3-.9 3.1-.1.9.9.9 2.3.1 3.1l-14.2 14.7c-.8.9-2.2.9-3.1.1z"
          fill="#002745"/>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I never thought this going to be solved by transform-origin but why we need to add seconds hand in group ? and this not working in my full svg code this clock is part of it

Comment: @Fathy because there is a transform already applied to seconds-hand so you will override it with the rotation, adding a group will allow us to have both transformation

Comment: @Fathy if the SVG is different, my code won't work because the center will probably change and you need another origin

Comment: transform-origin takes the center of parent svg ? or the center of it group and how can i adjust it to the right center position

Comment: @Fathy use `transform-origin: X% Y%` and adjust the value X/Y based on your case

Comment: i solved this by using transform-origin with transform-box my svg was different from the svg that embedded in question, group trick was so helpful thx